# I'm having trouble creating a function to search for a string in my linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have been working on a project and I'm figuring out the logistics for it so I'm making the basic functions before implementing them into the actual program. I have been building a big linked list with a group of words being read from a txt file called words.txt. After reading the words and putting them in the linked list, I've been trying for so long to get some functions working but I can't. The first is searching for a string from the linked list and printing it after printing the rest of the list. (I don't need to print the word for my program I just need to find it, but for now, I'm printing it to test the function.) The second is to delete a word that I search for from the linked list. In the source code, I only included the code for trying to search for the word because I deleted the delete function entirely because I wanted to start from scratch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Node of linked list*/
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;

/*Void function to print list*/
void printList(struct node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

/*Appending nodes to linked list*/
void add(char *line) {
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = strdup(line);
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}

void readfile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    char buffer[512];
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        add(buffer);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

node *listSearch(node* start, char nodeSearched){
    node *p;
    for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        if (strcmp(p->data, nodeSearched) == 0)
            printf("%s", p);
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    readfile("words.txt");
    printList(start);
    listSearch(start, "word");
    return 0;
}
```

[Link to the txt file in case you need it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoiYHSFfzsQ_hGtPhzqSu8bCABV0Nawc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `node *listSearch(node* start, char nodeSearched){` Shouldn't that be: `node *listSearch(node* start, char* nodeSearched){` ? The second parameter should be `char*` and not `char`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work

Comment: I wasn't telling you what to do, I was asking for clarification. I thought that maybe you made a mistake when you copied your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but with few mistakes. The string in your node also contains `\n` in the end. Try to handle that in readfile function or you can search `word\n` instead of `word`, this will give you the correct answer. And use `char* nodeSearched`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. contains appropriate error checking
3. performs the desired functionality
4. contains `//cleanup` comments where you need to actually return each allocated memory area to the heap, via `free()`  Otherwise, if an error occurs, the code will leak memory
5. Notice the separation of the struct from the `typedef` for that struct, for flexibility.
6. notice the use of `#define` statements to avoid 'magic' numbers
7. notice the removal of the trailing `\n` from each word input
8. notice the moving of the `global` variables to internal to the `main()` function and the appropriate passing of parameters from the `main()` function to the sub functions
9. notice the special handling of the first entry to the linked list
10. notice the call to `printf()` after the comments `//debug` to make it easy to distinguish between calls to `printf()` that are part of the functionality of the program and calls to `printf()` for debugging
11. notice the use of capitalization for macro names and for `typedef` names
12. notice I used the input file you provided
13. notice that in C, a NULL string can be tested without referencing `NULL`.  This greatly helps to 'de-clutter' the code
14. it is a poor programming practice to use variable and struct names ( `file` and `FILE` ) that differ only in capitalization. so replaced `file` with `fp` (a typical shorthand for `file descriptor pointer)
15. notice the use of appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for ease of readability by us humans

and now, the proposed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN  512
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 20


/*Node of linked list*/
struct node 
{
    char data[ MAX_WORD_LEN ];
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;


/*Void function to print list*/
void printList( NODE *head)
{
    NODE *current = head;
    
    while ( current ) 
    {
        printf("list value: %s\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}


/*Appending nodes to linked list*/
void addNode( NODE **head, char *line ) 
{
    
    NODE *temp = malloc(sizeof( NODE ));
    if ( ! temp )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        //todo: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    // implied else, malloc successful
    
    strcpy( temp->data, line );
    temp->next = NULL;
    
    NODE *current = *head;

    if( ! current ) 
    { // then, first node
        //debug
        //printf( "%s\n", "adding first node" );
        *head = temp;
    } 
    
    else 
    {
        while( current->next ) 
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        
        //debug
        //printf( "%s\n", "appending new node" );
        current->next = temp;
    }
}


void readfile( NODE **head, char *filename) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if( ! fp ) 
    { 
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    // implied else, fopen successful
    
    char buffer[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];
    while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp ) ) 
    {
        // remove (possible) trailing newline
        buffer [ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        
        //debug
        //printf( "result of fgets: %s\n", buffer );
        
        addNode( head, buffer );
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


NODE *listSearch( NODE *head, char *dataToFind )
{
    NODE *current = NULL;
    
    for ( current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        //debug
        //printf( "searching found: %s\n", current->data );
        if (strcmp( current->data, dataToFind ) == 0)
        {
            printf( "%s\n", current->data );
            break;
        }
    }
    return current;
}


int main( void )
{
    NODE *head = NULL;

    readfile( &head, "words.txt");
    printList( head );
    char searchWord[] = "word";
    
    NODE *foundNode = listSearch( head, searchWord );
    if( ! foundNode )
    {
        printf( "search for >%s< failed\n", searchWord );
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf( "search for: >%s< successful\n", searchWord );
    }
    
    // cleanup
    for( NODE *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        free( current );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```